# How to generate CREATE TABLE queries through plpgsql-function

Tags: postgresql, export, plpgsql, create-table

I need to export data structure and content from PostgreSQL tables without using pgdump service and without middleware. I wrote a function to export of all tables' data with INSERT queries: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/a3609/1/0 .

But how to determine the most effective way for `CREATE TABLE` queries generation through plpgsql function?

Comment: try https://github.com/VaoTsun/get_ddl_primitive?.. it is set of several plpgsql functions to generate ddl for tables

Comment: Thank you for this useful tool. By the way I found a problem with my code - I didn't think about order of the queries. Queries for the tables without foreign keys should go first and so on.